# What is the the expression '(void*)&this->A' meaning?

Tags: c++

In C++, is the expression `(void*)&this->A` equivalent to the expression `void this->A`? I found it in the source code as a function input parameter. Why do it do this? what is the difference between `(void*)&this->A` and `void this->A`?

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of asterisk `*` in the first expression?

Comment: You might be asking what `(void*)` before _anything_ means.  Or you might be asking what `&` before something means.  Or are you asking what `this->A` means?  I'm not sure.

Comment: Make sure you understand all these : address-of operator (`&`); casting; void pointer (`void *`)

Comment: In Windows programming pretty much anything API related will be cast to a (void*) when being passed around, its normal, nothing to worry about.  You can safely* pick it up on the other side and use it as whatever it was meant to be.  (I'm assuming you're doing Windows stuff like VC++, it is very common there.  *Safely: may or may not be safe)

Comment: What is the meaning of "let's eat, grandma!"? Is it the same as "let's eat grandma!"?

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: I'm sorry, it's my mistake that doesn't describe it clearly. I know that the symbol can get the address, *P can get the value that the pointer P points, and I know that *&amp;P is equivalent to P, so I asked that what is the difference between (void*)&this->A and void this->A. But, I see now, thank everyone.

Answer (score 2):

`(void*)&this->A` casts the address of `this->A` as a void pointer.

You mentioned this was being passed as a function input parameter - it's probably being cast this way because the function requires a `void*` argument, and `this->A` is natively some other type.

Comment: Your answer is great! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

<del>It's confusing due to the lack of parens, but it will essentially be a pointer (typeof `void *`) to `this->A`.</del> The order of operations may be confusing, but it will essentially be a pointer (typeof `void *`) to `this->A`. The type of what it points to, `this->A`, has been casted away and is `void`.

One reason to do this is so you can pass values through an external API, without it being aware of your own types. e.g. Callbacks that return user defined data & contexts.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Foo {
    int A;

    void bar() {
        cout << (void *)&this->A << endl;
        cout << (void *)(&(this->A)) << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Foo f{2};
    f.bar();

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs (on my machine):

```
0x7ffee8b01658
0x7ffee8b01658
```

So, `(void *)&this->A` and `(void *)(&(this->A))` are equivalent.

Comment: `(void*)(&(this->A))` is confusing due to the unnecessary parens.

Comment: lol. On second look, that reads like I'm suggesting more parens, which I'm totally against.

Comment: I thought that might have been the case. <g>